# How do i count number of the same class/id in selected options with javascript

Tags: javascript

```
Question1 
<select class="form-control" id="typePkt">
     <option class="eko4">12.000.0000</option>
     <option class="eko5">13.000.0000</option>
     <option class="siv1">14.000.0000</option>
     <option class="siv2">15.000.0000</option>
     <option class="pla1">16.000.0000</option>
</select>
Question2
 <select class="form-control" id="typePkt">
     <option class="eko4">12.000.0000</option>
     <option class="eko5">13.000.0000</option>
     <option class="siv1">14.000.0000</option>
     <option class="siv2">15.000.0000</option>
     <option class="pla1">16.000.0000</option>
</select>
```

above is example code... if i want to count the total class that i've selected how do i do that?
ex: question 1 -> option class eko5
question 2 -> option class eko 5
display :
all you pick : 2

Comment: You have duplicated `id` for your `select`s

Comment: And if the selected classes are not the same, what would you display ?

Comment: Do you have any code of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code that you may use to get what you want :

Please note that you have to use different `id` for each of your HTML elements.

```js
function countClasses() {
  //Get the first select
  var sel1 = document.getElementById('typePkt1');
  
  //Get the value of the class attribute of the selected option
  selectedClass1 = sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].getAttribute("class");
  
  //Get the second select
  var sel2 = document.getElementById('typePkt2');
  
  //Get the value of the class attribute of the selected option
  selectedClass2 = sel2.options[sel2.selectedIndex].getAttribute("class");

  console.log('selected classes : '+selectedClass1+' '+selectedClass2);
}
```

```html
Question1 
<select class="form-control" id="typePkt1">
     <option class="eko4">12.000.0000</option>
     <option class="eko5">13.000.0000</option>
     <option class="siv1">14.000.0000</option>
     <option class="siv2">15.000.0000</option>
     <option class="pla1">16.000.0000</option>
</select>
Question2
 <select class="form-control" id="typePkt2">
     <option class="eko4">12.000.0000</option>
     <option class="eko5">13.000.0000</option>
     <option class="siv1">14.000.0000</option>
     <option class="siv2">15.000.0000</option>
     <option class="pla1">16.000.0000</option>
</select>
<button onClick="countClasses();"> Count</button>
```

Comment: thank you for helping, but i was wonder if maybe i'm able to cont all the classes that i'll pick and display it otomaticly.. like, i picked same 'eko5' on question 1 and question 2. then it will display : "you pick 2 eko5"

Comment: sorry i'm beginner in javascript